# Regular expression which has @ because of that page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a regular expression for checking email. This function is works in a .js file, but in a HTML file because of the `@` in the expression the whole page shows? (Not Load). If I remove `@` from the regular expression then the page loads properly but then the expression is not validating emails properly.

How can I make this regular expression work in a .cshtml file? The expression is:

```
var filter = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
```

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code to reproduce the issue.?

Comment: Also check the console for errors.

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the `@` sign like so `@@`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra `@` sign to escape the razor keyword.

```
var filter = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
```

As a side note, I'd recommend that you don't validate emails too much as this can prevent valid international addresses such as this Chinese example:

> 用户@例子.广告